# Question closed as dupe is not a dupe

Tags: discussion, reopen-request, exact-duplicates

The question [Google Chrome pinned to Windows 7 taskbar not opening under pinned icon](https://superuser.com/questions/383102/google-chrome-pinned-to-windows-7-taskbar-not-opening-under-pinned-icon/427823#427823) was closed on Sept 3 as being a duplicate of [Some taskbar pinned icons are duplicated when an instance of the application is running](https://superuser.com/questions/214400/some-taskbar-pinned-icons-are-duplicated-when-an-instance-of-the-application-is/519650).

I don't think this is correct, as the "original" question asked about Windows 7 applications in general, while the so-called "dupe" specifically asks about Google Chrome, and has Chrome-specific solutions – and is in fact a very helpful question for people searching for this issue.

I've flagged the question, but I wanted to bring it up here also.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, in some way it *is* a duplicate. The specific question about Chrome not pinning to the taskbar is an instance of the general problem described in the other question.

Closing it would be a logical step, and we often do that in such cases.

Now, in this situation, the "general" solutions obviously didn't work, and there are more specific solutions to the Chrome issue. The question also happens to have more views than the actual duplicate. So, I reopened it.